# LocalTest.me with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, localhost, remote-access, web-testing

The LocalTest.me documentation says to find the site in IIS express that interests you, and to add a binding.

But my IIS Express has no "websites that interest me". There's only a single site called website1. Is that the one that is invoked when my Visual Studio web app is invoked. I have it set to "run a specific page" in my project, with (for example) mypage.aspx.

It runs correctly under: http://localhost:62293/mypage.aspx

a. To which site should I add the binding ?
b. When I add the binding should it be (as in the docs):

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1337:localtest.me" />
```

or should it be with the port that VS IIS Express is giving it:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62293:localtest.me" />
```

c. Last but not least: When I call it in the browser, do I write:

```
http://localtest.me/mypage.aspx
```

or:

```
http://localtest.me:62293/mypage.aspx
```

or maybe even

```
htp://localtest.me:1337/mypage.aspx
```

d. And one last thing (proving I'm American, by saying 'and one last thing': 
How can I set the Visual Studio 2015 (application: properties: settings: web) so that it opens to the localtest.me site instead of to the localhost?

e. One last last thing, although this is exactly what I'll be checking, when all the rest has been sorted out: Do you think I can run a web test like CloudQA or similar programs remotely once I have localTest.me up and running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The guys at CloudQA pointed me to ngork which works perfectly.